# How can I implement a dialog like Windows when I input an invalid file name with QT?

Tags: qt, dialog

I'm a QT programmer, now I need to enable users to specify a name for an object in my program. There's a rule that the name can only contain several characters, and if user inputs an invalid character, I want to pop up a dialog to indicate the error, like Windows does (see the attached image). I have implemented a sub-class deriving from QRegExpValidator, and can successfully obtain the signal when it fails to validate. But how can I implement a dialog like this? Anyone has any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Nope you just press the tickmark below the voting buttons. (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [QToolTip::showText()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtooltip.html#showText-2)